# Recursive template instantiation exceeded error in dtor, but not in ctor. Why?

Tags: c++, templates

Try clang++ and g++, same result for both.
`fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth`

```
template<class T>
struct Bar {
  ~Bar() {
    if (ptr) { delete ptr; }
  }
  Bar<Bar<T>> * ptr{nullptr};
};

int main() { Bar<void> obj; }
```

But ctor version compiles without error:

```
template<class T>
struct Bar {
  Bar() {
    if (ptr) { delete ptr; }
  }
  Bar<Bar<T>> * ptr{nullptr};
};

int main() { Bar<void> obj; }
```

What's the problem with dtor version?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need to test whether a pointer is null before deleting it. `delete` handles null pointers correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What's the problem with dtor version?

Think about what a declaration like `Bar<void> obj;` means.

That object needs have its destructor called when `main` returns. So the destructor  `~Bar<void>` will be instantiated.

What does the instantiated destructor contain? A `delete` expression. You may reason that it's under a nullity check, and so will never be *executed*, but that doesn't matter. C++ code is resolved statically, and must be correct **even when** a compiler can eliminate dead code.

That `delete` expression will need to invoke the destructor of `Bar<Bar<void>>`, and it must therefore be instantiated... Rinse and repeat.

On the other hand, in the constructor version, you have a trivial destructor. It does nothing, and certainly doesn't needs to instantiate any other type. So it compiles just fine when the constructor has to instantiate it.